# Unable to remove editor via User object returned from .getEditors()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am developing a web app for work that adds an editor to a spreadsheet and then removes that editor when his/her step is complete.

I am running into an issue where I can't remove the editor via the `User` object. The `User` object returned by `.getActiveUser()` isn't found in the `User[]` array returned by `.getEditors()`.

Example:

```
var editors = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getEditors() //returns User[]
var user = Session.getActiveUser();  //returns User
return editors.indexOf(user) // returns -1
```

This happens even though the active user is an editor of the spreadsheet in question.

I can get around this issue by removing the user via email address (i.e. `removeEditor(email)`), but this seems like an extra step.

Does anyone know why these two `User` objects wouldn't be the same? Is this a bug?

Comment: The return type for `Session.getActiveUser()` is `User`.  But that is a class.  I don't think that you can use that User Class for comparison tests.  You need to get the email:  `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`